# Prolog- procedure "?-A" does not exist

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get familiar with Prolog and running a very, very simple program.

```
father(tom, john).  
father(jerry, john).

sibling(A, B) :-father(A, F), father(B, F).
```

When I run `?- sibling(tom,jerry)`
I expect True, but am receiving Procedure "?-A" does not exist. 
Is there a syntactical error? Or a different way to run the query?

Comment: The syntax error is that atoms must begin with lowercase letters (or be quoted) because if the first letter is capitalized, Prolog will treat it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not have anything as knowledge! You are using capitals in `father` predicate. As you know the capitals use for the variables. So, you need to write something likes the following:

```
father(w, c).
father(g, c).
sibling(A, B) :-father(A, F), father(B, F).
```

Also, be aware that with your definition `w` is `sibling` of `w` (itself) too! Also, if you want to make it true in a semantic manner, you can rewrite it likes the follwoing:

```
father(w, c).
father(g, c).
sibling(A, B) :- A \== B, father(A, F), father(B, F).
```

Comment: I'm learning from a book that uses uppercase X & Y. Thanks for clarifying. The lowercase results in a singleton variable error, not Procedure error. I've updated the code (updated the original post to reflect changes), however, STILL receiving procedure does not exist error.

Comment: @jdgo12 Are you actually typing the '?- ' You shouldn't. It's just the query prefix.